# Problem with OAuth in accessing Google Contacts

Tags: php, google-contacts-api

I am trying to import the contacts of a person using google contacts API in the following PHP code . It uses OAuth 1.0 protocol :

```
<?php
    $consumer_key="www.spats.in";
    $secret="***********************";
    $mt = microtime();
    $rand = mt_rand();
    $nonce = md5($mt.$rand);

    $url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken";
    $params="oauth_callback=www.spats.in/nssc2/gmailContactsImport.php".
            "&oauth_consumer_key=$consumer_key".
            "&oauth_nonce=$nonce".
            "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1".
            "&oauth_timestamp=".time().
            "&oauth_version=1.0".
            "&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";

    $base_string = "GET&".urlencode($url).'?'.urlencode($params);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $secret, true));
    $params.="&oauth_signature=".$signature;

    $result=file_get_contents($url."?".$params);
    echo $result;
?>
```

However, on executing the php code, the result is as follows :

```
signature_invalid base_string:GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dwww.spats.in%252Fnssc2%252FgmailContactsImport.php%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dwww.spats.in%26oauth_nonce%3D36bc2ce5f00b79300d753bb94dc924df%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1308644840%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Fm8%252Ffeeds%252F
```

What is the problem with the signature? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I thought encoding the signature twice might be the problem [ once using urlencode() and second using base64_encode() ] , so I removed the base64_encode(). Now it shows Error 400 : Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.

Comment: Here is a similar, or rather exactly what you want in this [BLOG POST ON 9LESSONS.com](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/06/import-gmail-contacts-google-oauth.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okkay, the problem was with the key. I solved it myself.